# Divide 100 in equal percentages in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok. I will try to explain my case as good as I can.

Basically, I have this function here that will add an increment to my bootstrap progressbar:

```
function progress(increment) {
  f = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar')[0].style.width);
  document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar')[0].style.width = (f + increment) +'%';
}
```

Now for each step, for instance there are 6 steps, I must divide 100 into 6 steps incrementally.

For instance, if we are in step 1: `100 / 6 = 16.67 each` so this must add `16.67` incrementally.

So it would be like this:

```
Step 1: Add 16.67
Step 2: Add 33.34
Step 3: Add 50.01
---- and the list go on
```

So on my program I have the ff variables:

```
   let current_step = 0;
   let stepCount = 6
```

So if I used the progress function, I tried dividing 100 to stepCount to the current_step:

```
progress(100 / (stepCount - current_step)
```

But this did not resolve the issue and I am getting only weird numbers.

Any idea what's the proper formula here to get the right numbers to add on the progressbar?

PS. Sorry, I hope its not that confusing. I tried to explain this at the best I can.

Comment: `100 * (current_step / stepCount)` so you go towards 100 in equal steps. Otherwise you just divide by 6, then by 5, then by 4, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation isn't correct. This should give you the correct value.

```
progress((100 / stepCount) * current_step);

function progress(value) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar')[0].style.width = `${value}%`;
}
```

or you can do it like this

```
progress(100 / stepCount);

function progress(increment) {
    let f = +document.querySelector('.progress-bar')[0].style.width.slice(0, -1);
    // I'm slicing the width to remove the `%`
    document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar')[0].style.width = `${f + increment}%`;
}
```